# Gcloud dataflow job failed to write to temp location

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

[image]I am invoking dataflow job using gcloud cli. My command looks like below;

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run avrojob4 \
--gcs-location=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_Bigtable_to_GCS_Avro \
--region=europe-west1 \
--parameters bigtableProjectId="project-id",bigtableInstanceId="instance-id",bigtableTableId="table-id",outputDirectory="gs://avro-data/avrojob4/",filenamePrefix="avrojob4-"
```

and:

```
ERROR: Failed to write a file to temp location 'gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-473832897378/temp/'. Please make sure that the bucket for this directory exists, and that the project under which the workflow is running has the necessary permissions to write to it.
```

Can someone help me how to pass temp location as specific value through above command?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `--temp-location` flag for this command:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run

I suspect you're attempting to solve the issue by creating the flag but, as you've seen this does not work.

- Does the bucket exist?
- Does the Dataflow service account have suitable permissions to write to it?

Can you `gsutil ls gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-473832897378`?

if yes, then it's likely that the Dataflow service does not have permission to write to the bucket. Please review the instructions in the following link for adding the correct permissions for the Dataflow (!) service account:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_cloud_storage_buckets_across_google_cloud_platform_projects

Comment: Hi , the problem is I don't see the bucket name listed in my storage space(Also when I tried creating the bucket with exact name as mentioned in the error log, it says bucket name taken already). Hence I was trying to link the existing bucket to my job using some param if possible

Comment: I tried executing the above command and it says "AccessDeniedException: 403 chef-cronjobs@b-chef2-dqs-1eqs757.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to dataflow-staging-us-central1-473832897378."

Comment: whereas I could do the same(gsutil ls) for other buckets listed under "Storage browser" in my project with the same service account as above

Comment: I suspect that you're trying to use someone else's bucket (perhaps Google's from the documentation). You will need to create and then reference your own GCS bucket.

Comment: I have created my own bucket but I am not sure how to reference it.. Can you point me to some example or docs? (as in how to point my GCS bucket to the dataflow command)

Comment: Respectfully, your question has been answered. I recommend you review Google's documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#wordcount_1

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you at all. In my command I am pointing to my own GCS bucket (outputDirectory="gs://avro-data/avrojob4/) and I am not sure how to make my job use a specific temporary location other than "gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-473832897378/temp/" which is not even listed in my storage bucket to check for permissions. 
Anyways thank you!